# Generics for varied option parameter in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have an app in which I want to create **multiple configurable parallel workers**. The configuration is done via an **"options" parameter** because I want to have an interface that requires *Run(options) method*.

Each worker *(called thread in the snippet)* has its own configuration type *(ThreadAOptions for ThreadA and ThreadBOptions for ThreadB in the snippet)* that is passed optionally in Run() method "options" parameter. If no parameter is passed then default configuration values are used.

### My question is:

- **How can I rewrite generics in the snippet in a better way? Or is it the best solution?**

  - e.g. it would be fine to be able to call RunThread() method in App without the second ("options") parameter, however, it is not possible to set "TOptions options = null" at this time because of compiler error: "A value of type 'null' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type 'TOptions'"
  - ...or is there any best practice to do that?

The source code snippet is intentionally simplified because in real use case it contains a lot of non-relevant code for this review.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App
{
    public interface IOptions
    {
        public void Validate();   
    }

    public interface IThread<in TOptions> where TOptions : IOptions?
    {
        public Task Run(TOptions options);
    }

    public class ThreadAOptions : IOptions
    {
        public int SleepTime = 5000; // in ms

        public void Validate()
        {
            if (SleepTime < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(SleepTime));
        }
    }

    public class ThreadA : IThread<ThreadAOptions>
    {
        public async Task Run(
            ThreadAOptions? options
        )
        {
            options ??= new ThreadAOptions();
            options.Validate();

            Thread.Sleep(options.SleepTime);
        }
    }

    public class ThreadBOptions : IOptions
    {
        public int AnotherSleepTime = 5000; // in ms

        public void Validate()
        {
            if (AnotherSleepTime < 10) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(AnotherSleepTime));
        }
    }

    public class ThreadB : IThread<ThreadBOptions>
    {
        public async Task Run(
            ThreadBOptions? options
        )
        {
            options ??= new ThreadBOptions();
            options.Validate();

            Thread.Sleep(options.AnotherSleepTime);
        }
    }

    internal class App {
        private readonly ThreadA _threadA;
        private readonly ThreadB _threadB;

        // Dependencies loaded via DI
        public App(
            ThreadA threadA,
            ThreadB threadB
        )
        {
            _threadA = threadA;
            _threadB = threadB;
        }

        // Called from outside of the class (Program.cs)
        public async Task Init()
        {
            var workers = new List<Task>
                {
                    RunThread<ThreadA, ThreadAOptions>(_threadA, null),
                    RunThread(_threadB, new ThreadBOptions() {
                      AnotherSleepTime = 10000
                    }),
                };

            await Task.WhenAll(workers.ToArray());
        }

        private async Task RunThread<TThread, TOptions>(TThread thread, TOptions options)
            where TThread : IThread<TOptions> where TOptions : IOptions?
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(async () => { await thread.Run(options); });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Thread exception: {e.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to code review, where we review working code to and provide suggestions on how to improve that code. Code that has comments like `// ... code ...` is considered off topic because it it very hard to give a good review when there is code missing.

Comment: Welcome @pacmaninbw, thank you for your comment. I replaced these blocks to be more clear. I think that snippet is very easy to understand. It is written in a style that makes the question useful for more people than only me.

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Mast So, should I remove this question or should I copy & paste all relevant code (approx. 480 lines)?

Comment: For now, leave it be. The question might be closed. You can't remove it once it's answered and any attempts to modify the code will be seen as invalidation of the answer. The answerer failed to notice your question was off-topic and should've flagged the question or left a comment instead of answering, but what's done is done. I think the answer is valuable enough that the best course of action now is to leave it be. If you have a new question with updated code, feel free to post that as new question.

Comment: As for 480 lines of code, I'm sure you don't need to post all those lines but it's possible as long as it (including the description) stays under 65k characters. That's the technical limit. But at the moment, you have a lot of simplified names as well. Everything you simplify, is unnecessarily hard to review or will leave you with answers you can't do anything with since your actual situation will be different.

Comment: If it was up to me, we'd force-feed our [FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915) together with the [help/on-topic] to new users to prevent ugly situations like this. Alas, Stack Exchange thinks different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to improve the generics in the code snippet this way:

- Edit specification of `App.RunThread(...)` method to be able to call the method without the second parameter. Specifically, set the default value for the second parameter as `= default`. It means `null` for reference types (our case) and default value for value types. We cannot use `= null` in this case. [See a relevant question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32732271/1044198).
- Remove `TThread` from generics because we do not use it anywhere and we want to require `IThread` interface in fact. A side effect is that we do not have to specify option type explicitly when calling the method with null second argument because it can be now inferred from usage.

**Before:**

```
public async Task Init() {
    var workers = new List<Task>
    {
        RunThread<ThreadA, ThreadAOptions>(_threadA, null),
        RunThread(_threadB, new ThreadBOptions() {
            AnotherSleepTime = 10000
        }),
    };

    await Task.WhenAll(workers.ToArray());
}

private async Task RunThread<TThread, TOptions>(TThread thread, TOptions options)
            where TThread : IThread<TOptions> where TOptions : IOptions? { /* ... */ }
```

**After:**

```
public async Task Init()
{
    var workers = new List<Task>
    {
        RunThread(_threadA), // (_threadA, null) also works, but it is not necessary since null is a default value.
        RunThread(_threadB, new ThreadBOptions()
        {
            AnotherSleepTime = 10000
        }),
    };

    await Task.WhenAll(workers.ToArray());
}

private async Task RunThread<TOptions>(IThread<TOptions> thread, TOptions options = default)
            where TOptions : IOptions? { /* ... */ }
```

- Set `options = default` for each `Run(...)` method implementation
- Set Thread options as nullable e.g. `IThread<ThreadAOptions?>`

**Before:**

```
public class ThreadB : IThread<ThreadBOptions>
{
    public async Task Run(
        ThreadBOptions? options
    ) { /* ... */ }
}
```

**After:**

```
public class ThreadB : IThread<ThreadBOptions?>
{
    public async Task Run(
        ThreadBOptions? options = default
    ) { /* ... */ }
}
```

### The complete code after the review:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App
{
    public interface IOptions
    {
        public void Validate();
    }

    public interface IThread<in TOptions> where TOptions : IOptions?
    {
        public Task Run(TOptions options = default);
    }

    public class ThreadAOptions : IOptions
    {
        public int SleepTime = 5000; // in ms

        public void Validate()
        {
            if (SleepTime < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(SleepTime));
        }
    }

    public class ThreadA : IThread<ThreadAOptions?>
    {
        public async Task Run(
            ThreadAOptions? options = default
        )
        {
            options ??= new ThreadAOptions();
            options.Validate();

            Thread.Sleep(options.SleepTime);
        }
    }

    public class ThreadBOptions : IOptions
    {
        public int AnotherSleepTime = 5000; // in ms

        public void Validate()
        {
            if (AnotherSleepTime < 10) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(AnotherSleepTime));
        }
    }

    public class ThreadB : IThread<ThreadBOptions?>
    {
        public async Task Run(
            ThreadBOptions? options = default
        )
        {
            options ??= new ThreadBOptions();
            options.Validate();

            Thread.Sleep(options.AnotherSleepTime);
        }
    }

    internal class App
    {
        private readonly ThreadA _threadA;
        private readonly ThreadB _threadB;

        // Dependencies loaded via DI
        public App(
            ThreadA threadA,
            ThreadB threadB
        )
        {
            _threadA = threadA;
            _threadB = threadB;
        }

        // Called from outside of the class (Program.cs)
        public async Task Init()
        {
            var workers = new List<Task>
            {
                RunThread(_threadA),
                RunThread(_threadB, new ThreadBOptions()
                {
                    AnotherSleepTime = 10000
                }),
            };

            await Task.WhenAll(workers.ToArray());
        }

        private async Task RunThread<TOptions>(IThread<TOptions> thread, TOptions options = default)
            where TOptions : IOptions?
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(async () => { await thread.Run(options); });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Thread exception: {e.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```